# Как сохранить состояние чекбоксов?

Tags: java, checkbox

Создал приложение в котором есть несколько чекбоксов. К примеру выбрал несколько из них. Когда повторно открываю эту форму с чекбоксами выбранные значения исчезают. Мне нужно как-то сохранить выбранные чекбоксы.

Comment: Сохранить инфу в БД, например

Comment: Создал приложение в котором есть несколько чекбоксов. К примеру выбрал несколько из них. Когда повторно открываю эту форму с чекбоксами выбранные значения исчезают.
Мне нужно как-то сохранить выбранные чекбоксы.

Comment: У тебя куча вариантов есть. База (SQLite если приложение десктопное или андроидное), сериализация в файл, xml-сериализация, проперти -файл.

Comment: А язык указать? Ну и вообще проблема крайне банальна. Сводится к сохранению переменной в памяти. На этот счет бесчисленное количество уроков. @rvit34 описал куда надо двигаться. Ну или больше конкретики в вопросе. Какой язык, платформа и т.д.